# How to filter queryset by ForeignKey and ManyToMany using Q properly?

Tags: python, django

I got an error message that says:

> 'User' object does not support indexing

I try to filter queryset using Q to get a query that contains objects where `self.request.user` (which is an User model object) is an `owner` (ForeignKey) or one of the `participants` (ManyToMany).

Here is my code:

```
if self.request.user.has_perm('permissions'):
    queryset = self.model.objects.filter(parent=None)
else:
    queryset = self.model.objects.filter(Q(parent=None),
                                         Q(owner=self.request.user) | Q(participants__in=self.request.user))
```

I think the problem is `Q(participants__in=self.request.user)` but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from this `Q(participants__in=self.request.user)` when you use [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in) you have to specify an iterable.

Can you post models?

Comment: To complete the answer, it should be `Q(participants=self.request.user)`.